# Small bathroom - feasible layout?

Tags: bathroom, uk, layout

With a tiny (5' by 6') bathroom we never have enough space. Current layout is like this:

[image: old]

Is the following feasible? Particularly in terms of drainage from the shower?

[image: new]

[image: actual bath]

Currently the bath "waste" is directly by the window (where the waste for the toilet etc goes to outside) so there isn't any need to take it across/under the floor. I don't think there is any pipework "under" the floor currently.

Is it an option to have pipes above floor level but boxed in - would be happy with that.

I don't have a great deal of wall space as one wall is windows the whole width of the room (about 12" above the level of the sink/cistern).

Is there another layout (in general terms) you would recommend? My aim is really just to have a sense of more space and to have enough storage, (we're not concerned with keeping the bath) I realise it's a really small space.

Comment: Are you asking about vertical fall of the piping below the floor? Tell us about that space. This shouldn't be a problem otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for editing with the images- I'm not sure why they were broken. I was doing it on the mobile app..

Comment: @seventyeightist At the bottom of the post it keeps the links for the images. Like.. "[1]: http://imgur.com/06tYO8g.jpg"... your links were missing the ".jpg" to turn it into an image.

Comment: "where the waste for the toilet etc goes to outside" -- let me guess, this is in the UK

Comment: @amphibient - yes, UK, sorry if I haven't used quite the right terms - I'm a bit unfamiliar with all this..

Comment: no problem.  i remember the 4" pipe eye sore on many houses from my one trip to the otherwise beautiful country :)

Comment: ....What happens with the toilets elsewhere?? Naive question I know!

Comment: Maybe switch the door to open against the wall?

Answer (score 1):

> **Is it an option to have pipes above floor level but boxed in**

Yes.

But if the hot and cold water supply pipes in and are metal (copper) and have supplementary equipotential bonding - I think you need to make sure the bonding clamps are easily accessible without tools. Ditto for isolating valves (for when you want to replace taps).

You don't need much slope on the horizontal runs of the waste pipe (and too much slope is bad) I read 1 in 40 to 1 in 110 somewhere.

I've boxed in pipework minimally but if I did it again I'd try to make more of a feature of it - cupboards with useful storage space as well as access to pipes.

Comment: Looking from above to outside (there's another floor above the bathroom), the toilet waste comes out exactly into the outflow pipe and the waste from the sink and bath comes out into the length of that pipe (a bit further down), so it seems like currently they are optimally placed in terms of distance to outside, although not optimally placed for anyone wanting to actually use the bathroom. If boxed in I'm happy to have a "hatch" or whatever to access the necessary parts. Are you saying there shouldn't be much of an issue with the shower waste (now mid room) to the outside?